# How can I authorize gmail API using AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gmail-api

So I trying to get all mails from gmail account via aws lambda.
When i test it locally all works fine.
When i upload the lambda it says 
" java.io.IOException: unable to create directory tokens"

I use this code :

```
 private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = TlvPartnersClient.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize(TLV_PARTNER_MAIL);
    }
```

Comment: What path is TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH pointing to? Be sure to point any (temporary) storage in your lambda to /tmp. Not sure if you have the necessary permissions for creating directories anywhere outside of tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Lamdbda Functions run on top of Amazon Linux and its only writable directory is /tmp.

Definitely your TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH is not pointing to /tmp, thus the java.io.IOException. If TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH is some kind of Windows path (C:*) it will not work either.

Also keep in mind that the you have a 512MB limit of temp storage within Lambda Functions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html